# Awkward Linq Sort

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Foo objects:

```
List<Foo>
```

Foo itself contains a Bar property, which contains a list of Bazs that have a DateTime property named DateHappened:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public List<Baz> Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to sort my list of Foos based on the earliest value of the DateHappened property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ordered = fooList
    .SelectMany(f => f.Bar.Bazs.Select(b => new { Foo = f, DT = b.DateTime }))
    .OrderBy(fd => fd.DT)
    .Select(fd => fd.Foo);
```

If you want to order by the minimum time in each `Baz` list you can do:

```
var ordered = fooList
    .OrderBy(f => f.Bar.Bazs.Select(b => b.DateTime).Min());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var ordered = fooList.OrderBy(f => f.Bar.Baz.Min(b => b.DateHappened));
```